# How to make a downloaded file visible in File Manager after written/downloaded into Android?

Tags: android

I have successfully downloaded the file from the server and saved it on Android storage, but the file is stored in a deep path, for example: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/example.com.yourapp/files/Download/example_file.pdf`

The code I'm currently using is like this:

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) {
        try {
            File filesDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            assert filesDir != null;

            downloadedFile = new File(filesDir,
                    "file_name" + ".pdf");

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

            try {
                byte[] fileReader = new byte[4096];

                long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

                inputStream = body.byteStream();
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadedFile);

                while (true) {
                    int read = inputStream.read(fileReader);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read);

                    fileSizeDownloaded += read;
                }

                outputStream.flush();

                Functions.scanFile(getContext(), downloadedFile, "application/pdf");

                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What I want, when the download process is successful and I open the file manager, the latest file that already downloaded can be seen in the latest file before.

I don't know yet, but I think I need to make use of MediaStore to make my files visible in File Manager by trying this code:

```
public static void scanFile(Context ctxt, File f, String mimeType) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctxt, new String[] {f.getAbsolutePath()}, new String[] {mimeType}, null);
    }
```

But it didn't work either. How do i achieve this?

Comment: Files in your application directory can only be accessed by your application. Refreshing `MediaStore` will not make any difference because the file is not accessible by `MediaStore`. Rather save the file to the Downloads directory if you want other applications to have access to the file.

Comment: So how to make my file can be accessed by other application? I tried to save it to Download manager, as you can see in my code `File filesDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

Comment: A normal file manager will immediately show your file in your app specific directory. For Android 11 things changed. Please tell Android version  of device and name of used file manager.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, you are right. when I use the File Manager with the **Pixel 3a API 29** emulator and try to filter the files in the File Manager with the document type, my files are found because they are in the form of `.pdf`

but when I use File Manager from **Xiaomi** phones, I have to go deep into the folder directory to find my files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just change `File filesDir = getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`
into `File filesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

And it's available in recent files in File manager